# Calculate last week start date in JavaScript (not -7 days ago)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a list of activity records which all have a date and show in an activity stream.

I am wanting to insert a separator DIV between the records based on which date group they fall under based on the recordsa creation date.

I want to show a DIV with text **This week** which would take the start date of the current week (not past 7 days) and then I can show all my records created since that date.

I also want to do one for **Last week** which would mean I need to get the Date value for the start date of last week and the end date of last week.  Or Start date +7 would be fine.

I then have a JavaScript library to compare date ranges.  I can pass in a start date and end date and find out if a 3rd date is within the date range which would let me know which of my records to show under each Date section.

So I am asking for help in calculating the :

**A week start date is on a Sunday by most calendar or Monday**

- current week start date
- last week start date and end date

Also I prefer not to use the massive in size Moment.js library for these few date operations if I can help it.

Thanks for any help

This image below shows what I am trying to achieve with the date sections to break my records up...

[image]

---

**Date library for DateTime comparisons and checking if a date is in-between range of 2 dates!**

```
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497790
var dates = {
  convert: function(d) {
    // Converts the date in d to a date-object. The input can be:
    //   a date object: returned without modification
    //  an array      : Interpreted as [year,month,day]. NOTE: month is 0-11.
    //   a number     : Interpreted as number of milliseconds
    //                  since 1 Jan 1970 (a timestamp)
    //   a string     : Any format supported by the javascript engine, like
    //                  "YYYY/MM/DD", "MM/DD/YYYY", "Jan 31 2009" etc.
    //  an object     : Interpreted as an object with year, month and date
    //                  attributes.  **NOTE** month is 0-11.
    return (
      d.constructor === Date ? d :
      d.constructor === Array ? new Date(d[0], d[1], d[2]) :
      d.constructor === Number ? new Date(d) :
      d.constructor === String ? new Date(d) :
      typeof d === "object" ? new Date(d.year, d.month, d.date) :
      NaN
    );
  },
  compare: function(a, b) {
    // Compare two dates (could be of any type supported by the convert
    // function above) and returns:
    //  -1 : if a < b
    //   0 : if a = b
    //   1 : if a > b
    // NaN : if a or b is an illegal date
    // NOTE: The code inside isFinite does an assignment (=).
    return (
      isFinite(a = this.convert(a).valueOf()) &&
      isFinite(b = this.convert(b).valueOf()) ?
      (a > b) - (a < b) :
      NaN
    );
  },
  inRange: function(d, start, end) {
    // Checks if date in d is between dates in start and end.
    // Returns a boolean or NaN:
    //    true  : if d is between start and end (inclusive)
    //    false : if d is before start or after end
    //    NaN   : if one or more of the dates is illegal.
    // NOTE: The code inside isFinite does an assignment (=).
    return (
      isFinite(d = this.convert(d).valueOf()) &&
      isFinite(start = this.convert(start).valueOf()) &&
      isFinite(end = this.convert(end).valueOf()) ?
      start <= d && d <= end :
      NaN
    );
  },

  // Subtract number of months from current month
  // dates.subtractMonth(1)
  subtractMonth: function(numberOfMonths) {
    //var d = this;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - numberOfMonths);
    d.setDate(1);
    return d;
  }

};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

my sample JSON data with a date that will be compared with the other dates to determine when to inject a date section header into the loop

```
var task_activities = [{"id":1,"name":"record 1","date_time":"1\/5\/2015"},{"id":2,"name":"record 2","date_time":"1\/9\/2015"},{"id":3,"name":"record 3","date_time":"1\/13\/2015"},{"id":4,"name":"record 4","date_time":"1\/17\/2015"},{"id":5,"name":"record 5","date_time":"1\/21\/2015"},{"id":6,"name":"record 6","date_time":"1\/25\/2015"},{"id":7,"name":"record 7","date_time":"1\/29\/2015"},{"id":8,"name":"record 8","date_time":"2\/1\/2015"},{"id":9,"name":"record 9","date_time":"2\/5\/2015"},{"id":10,"name":"record 10","date_time":"2\/9\/2015"},{"id":11,"name":"record 11","date_time":"2\/13\/2015"},{"id":12,"name":"record 12","date_time":"2\/17\/2015"},{"id":13,"name":"record 13","date_time":"2\/21\/2015"},{"id":14,"name":"record 14","date_time":"2\/25\/2015"},{"id":15,"name":"record 15","date_time":"2\/29\/2015"},{"id":16,"name":"record 16","date_time":"3\/1\/2015"},{"id":17,"name":"record 17","date_time":"3\/5\/2015"},{"id":18,"name":"record 18","date_time":"3\/9\/2015"},{"id":19,"name":"record 19","date_time":"3\/13\/2015"},{"id":20,"name":"record 20","date_time":"3\/17\/2015"}];



// Loop over each Task Activity record and generate HTML
$.each(task_activities, function(i, activity) {
    console.log(activity.date_time);
}); // end each
```

Comment: Just subtract 1 from the day-of-month until the date object tells you that the day-of-week is whatever you want the start of the week to be.

Comment: @Pointy thanks I hadn't thought of that!  Also once I subtract to get the start of the current week, then I could simply subtract 7 days to get the start of last weeks, etc...gonna be much easier than I had though it was, thanks

Comment: The JavaScript Date stuff is not very sophisticated but it sure is easy to do simple stuff like this :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the *subtractMonth* function is flawed, for 31 March minus 1 month it returns 1 March.

If you want to find the first day of the week for a given date, just subtract the day number from the date for weeks starting on Sunday, or subtract one less day or 6 for Sunday for weeks starting on Monday:

```
/**
**  @param {Date} date - date to get start of week for
**  @param {Boolean} mondayStart - falsey for Sunday as first day of week,
**                                 truthy for Monday as first day of week
**  @returns {Date} - date for first day of week
*/
function getStartOfWeek(date, mondayStart) {

  // copy date
  var d = new Date(+date);
  // days to previous Sunday
  var shift = d.getDay();

  // Adjust shift if week starts on Monday
  if (mondayStart) {
    shift = shift? shift - 1 : 6;
  }

  // Shift to start of week
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - shift);
  return d;
}
```

If you want the *subtractMonth* function to work, say what you want it to do.

#### Edit

As a bonus feature, here's a subtract months function that works how I think it was intended to work:

```
/*
** @param {number} numberOfMonths - number of months to add to date
** @param {Date} date - date to subract months from
** @returns {Date} - the passed in date object with the specified number of months subtracted
*/
function subtractMonth (numberOfMonths, date) {

  // If date not supplied, default to today
  var d = date || new Date();

  // Get the date
  var day = d.getDate();

  // Subtract the months
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - numberOfMonths);

  // If date has changed, was too big for month and has rolled over
  // into next month, so set to last day of previous month
  if (day != d.getDate) d.setDate(0);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, they make a good addition to my little Date library.  The subtract month function seems to work good in that it has the correct ending date for the months.  One thing I wasn't sure of at first though was for example subtract 1 month from now shows `Jul 31` and as we are almost middle of September, it just seemed as it might of skipped August but I realize this is a tricky one as many people will have different needs.  In the end I am still not 100% sure on what I need for my end result but....continued...

Comment: using my `dates.inRange(d, start, end)` function and plugging these new date values in while iterating my JSON above I can determine where each record fits in... `Yesterday`, `This week`, `Last Week`, 'Earlier this Month`, 'Last Month`.  Once I get the date values I need, I am still not sure exactly how I am going to insert 1 date heading  in between my records.  For example if 5 records all fall under the range of `This week`, I will need to insert the Date heading `This Week`  only 1 time and above those 5 records.  After those 5 record it might get to a record that falls under `Last Week`..

Comment: ....Not sure if i'm even making sense.  The image I posted above probably explains better than words.  You code is  of the missing pieces though so thank you!

Comment: I am thinking maybe I could do a `switch()` and have each of my date conditions in it.  My JSON records date would then be passed into the switch and would determine whee it fits in (this week, last week, etc).  Do you have any ideas how I could insert yhis date heading DIV  for each group where it would be at the top of each of the records that fall under it.  I have a fiddle here with my JSON being iterated on and all these date functions for playing around.  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/Lq3ntrdu/

Comment: 1 idea I have is to maybe create a flag variable for each of the date sections and once 1 JSON record matches I set the flag indicating for that date section heading to not need to be created anymore.